# C++ creating a submatrix

Tags: c++, image-processing, matrix

For an assignment we have been asked to create a program that can unshuffle a jumpled 512x512 gray scale image (it was shuffled by being broken down into 32x32 blocks). The greyscale image is imported into the project via text file and then it uses a predefined function to convert the values into a 1d array. Using this we were tasked with creating a matrix class that can store and ultimately manipulate the image with the intention of restoring the shuffled image.

I am having issues with creating submatrices to use in a comparison fashion (my general idea is selecting the first 32x32 block from the shuffled and the normal image then compare their pixel values to find a match). the function for my getBlock function is as follows:

```
Matrix Matrix::getBlock(int startRow, int endRow, int startColumn, int endColumn)
{
    int Row = endRow - startRow;
    int Column = endColumn - startColumn;
    double* block = new double[(Row) *(Column)];
    int n = endColumn - startColumn;
    for (int ii = startRow; ii < endRow; ii++)
    {
        for (int jj = startColumn; jj < endColumn; jj++)
        {
            int k = ii*n + jj;
            block[k] = data[ii*N + jj];
        }
    }
    Matrix t(Row, Column, block);
    return t;
    delete[] block;
}
```

And in my main() i have attempted to implement the function as follows:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 480; x += 32) // so starts at 0 and continues if x less than 480 as 480 + 32 = 512
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 480; y += 32) // same as x but with y
    {           
        Matrix block = ShuffledCode.getBlock(x, (x + 32), y, (y + 32));

        cout << block.sum() << endl;                
    }
}
```

My issue arises whenever the start column and the start row become anything other than 0, for instance in the above code the value is displayed for the first block (startrow 0, endrow 32, startcolumn 0, endcolumn 32) correctly however when the loop iterates i get a heap corruption error and i can't figure out what is going wrong. Another observation is that if i increase the endrow and endcolumn above 32 (so for instance if i increased them to 64) it seems to function fine and return the correct value.

If anyone has any ideas what could be causing it i would be very grateful, been working on it for days and haven't made any progress. I have also included all my code below in case the problem is related to another part of the program. the source.cpp file:

```
#include <sstream> // stringstream
#include <iostream> // cout, cerr
#include <fstream> // ifstream
#include <istream>
#include <assert.h>
#include "Matrix.H"

using namespace std;

// Input data are provided in .txt format and can be converted to .pgm files for       visualization
// Download (free) ImageJ for plotting images in .pgm format
// http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/download.html

// Reads .txt file representing an image of R rows and C Columns stored in filename 
// and converts it to a 1D array of doubles of size R*C
// Memory allocation is performed inside readTXT
double* readTXT(char *fileName, int sizeR, int sizeC);

// Converts a 1D array of doubles of size R*C to .pgm image of R rows and C Columns 
// and stores .pgm in filename
// Use Q = 255 for greyscale images and Q=1 for binary images.
void WritePGM(char *filename, double *data, int sizeR, int sizeC, int Q);


int main()
{
// This part will show you how to use the two functions.

//M and N represent the number of rows and columns in the image,
//e.g. for task 1: logo_with_noise and logo_shuffled, M = 512, N = 512
//e.g. for task 2, Cluttered_scene, M = 768, N = 1024
//e.g. for task 2, Wally_grey, M = 49, N =  36
int M = 512; int N = 512; int count = 0;
// input_data is a pointer to a 1D array of M*N doubles stored in heap. Memory allocation is performed 
// inside readTXT. readTXT will read an image (in .pgm format) of size MxN and will  store the result in input_data.
// once you're done with data DO NOT forget to delete the memory as in the end of this main() function
double* input_data = 0;
double* noise_data = 0;

cout << endl;
cout << "Data from text file -------------------------------------------" << endl;

// shuffled image is stored in inputFileName, input_data holds the data in a 1d array
char* inputFileName = "C:\\Users\\Jamie\\SkyDrive\\Documents\\SoftwareDevAss\\ADS_Assignment\\Datafile\\logo_shuffled.txt";
input_data = readTXT(inputFileName, M, N);

// the img with noise is stored in inputFileName2, noise_data holds the data in a 1d array
char* inputFileName2 = "C:\\Users\\Jamie\\SkyDrive\\Documents\\SoftwareDevAss\\ADS_Assignment\\Datafile\\logo_with_noise.txt";
noise_data = readTXT(inputFileName2, M, N);

// this loop reduces the noise on the provided image to make it clear, uses threshold 170 as i found that gives the best results
for (int x = 0; x < 262144; x++)
{

    if (noise_data[x] < 170)
    {
        noise_data[x] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        noise_data[x] = 255;
    }
}


/*long int pLength = 262144; // total length in pixels of 1d array holding the image
long int bLength = 1024; // total length in pixels of each block (32x32)
long int cLength = 262144; // current remaning length in pixels of 1d array holding the image
long int sum = 0; // theoretical limit of 262144 (if all pixels are white thus have the value 255)
for (int rBlocks = 0; rBlocks < 254; rBlocks++)
{
    sum = 0;
    cLength = pLength - ((rBlocks) * 1024);
    double *sub = noise_data - cLength;
    assert(sub[0] == noise_data[bLength * rBlocks]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    {
        sum += sub[i];
    }
    cout << sum << endl;

}

*/


// at this point noise_data holds the original image.
Matrix ShuffledCode(512, 512, input_data);
Matrix SortedCode(512, 512, noise_data);
bool wedone = false;
int val = 1024;

// issue with increasing the start row and column above 0, end row and column can be increased fine.
for (int x = 0; x < 480; x += 32) // so starts at 0 and continues if x less than 480 as 480 + 32 = 512
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 480; y += 32) // same as x but with y
    {           
        Matrix block = ShuffledCode.getBlock(x, (x + 32), y, (y + 32));

        cout << block.sum() << endl;                
    }
}


/*for (int x = 0; x < 262144; x++)
{

            input_data[x] = noise_data[x];

}
*/

/*int MAX = 262144;
for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < MAX; j++)
    {
        if (input_data[i] == input_data[j] && noise_data[i] == noise_data[j])
        {

        }
        else
        {
            input_data[i] = noise_data[i];
            input_data[j] = noise_data[j];
        }
    }
}
*/


// writes data back to .pgm file stored in outputFileName
char* outputFileName = "C:\\Users\\Jamie\\SkyDrive\\Documents\\SoftwareDevAss\\ADS_Assignment\\Datafile\\logo_restored.pgm";
char* cleanFile = "C:\\Users\\Jamie\\SkyDrive\\Documents\\SoftwareDevAss\\ADS_Assignment\\Datafile\\logo_clean.pgm";
char* tester = "C:\\Users\\Jamie\\SkyDrive\\Documents\\SoftwareDevAss\\ADS_Assignment\\Datafile\\tester.pgm";
// Use Q = 255 for greyscale images and 1 for binary images.
int Q = 255;
WritePGM(outputFileName, input_data, M, N, Q);
WritePGM(cleanFile, noise_data, M, N, Q);

delete[] noise_data;
delete[] input_data;


return 0;
}

//Consructor
Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double* input_data)
{
M = sizeR;
N = sizeC;
data = new double[M*N];
for (int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
{
    data[ii] = input_data[ii];
}
}

Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC)
{
M = sizeR;
N = sizeC;
data = new double[M*N];

for (int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
{
    *(data + ii) = 0;
}
} 

//Destructor
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
delete[] data;
}

//Copy Constructor
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& existingMatrix)
{
M = existingMatrix.getM();
N = existingMatrix.getN();
data = new double[M*N];

for (int ii = 0; ii < M; ii++)
{
    for (int jj = 0; jj < N; jj++)
    {
        int k = ii*N + jj;
        data[k] = existingMatrix.get(ii, jj);
    }
}
}

//Pass by constant value
double Matrix::get(int i, int j)  const
{
int k = i*N + j;
return data[k];
}

//Pass by Refrence
const void Matrix::set(int i, int j, double& val)
{
int k = i*N + j;
val = data[k];
}

//Return Value of M
int Matrix::getM() const
{
return M;
}

//Return Value of N
int Matrix::getN() const
{
return N;
}

//Returns part of the matrix
Matrix Matrix::getBlock(int startRow, int endRow, int startColumn, int endColumn)
{
int Row = endRow - startRow;
int Column = endColumn - startColumn;
double* block = new double[(Row) *(Column)];
int n = endColumn - startColumn;
for (int ii = startRow; ii < endRow; ii++)
{
    for (int jj = startColumn; jj < endColumn; jj++)
    {
        int k = ii*n + jj;
        block[k] = data[ii*N + jj];
    }
}
Matrix t(Row, Column, block);
return t;
delete[] block;
}

//Allows for addion of Matricies, Operation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator +(const Matrix& B)
{
Matrix C = Matrix(M, N, 0);
double temp;
for (int ii = 0; ii < M; ii++)
{
    for (int jj = 0; jj < N; jj++)
    {
        temp = data[ii*N + jj] + B.get(ii, jj);
        C.set(ii, jj, temp);
    }
}

return C;
}

//Makes x and y equal, Opperation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator =(const Matrix& B)
{
if (this == &B)
{
    return *this;
}

else
{
    M = B.getM();
    N = B.getN();
    delete[] data;
    data = new double[M*N];
    for (int ii = 0; ii < M; ii++)
    {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < N; jj++)
        {
            data[ii*N + jj] = B.get(ii, jj);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
}

//Allows for subtraction of matricies, Operation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator -(const Matrix& B)
{
Matrix C = Matrix(M, N);
double temp;
for (int ii = 0; ii < M - 1; ii++)
{
    for (int jj = 0; jj < N - 1; jj++)
    {
        temp = data[ii*N + jj] - B.get(ii, jj);
        C.set(ii, jj, temp);
    }
}

return C;
}

//Allows for multiplication of Matricies, Operation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator *(const Matrix& B)
{
Matrix C = Matrix(M, B.getN());
double temp;
for (int ii = 0; ii < M; ii++)
{
    for (int jj = 0; jj < N; jj++)
    {
        temp = data[ii*N + jj] * B.get(ii, jj);
        C.set(ii, jj, temp);
    }
}

return C;
}

//Allows for addition of Matricies, Operation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator /(const Matrix& B)
{
Matrix C = Matrix(M, B.getN(), 0);
double temp;
for (int ii = 0; ii < M; ii++)
{
    for (int jj = 0; jj < N; jj++)
    {
        temp = data[ii*N + jj] / B.get(ii, jj);
        C.set(ii, jj, temp);
    }
}

return C;
}

//Incrmentation of all values in Matrix by 1, Operation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator ++()
{
for (int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
{
    data[ii] = data[ii]++;
}

return *this;
}


//Allows calling of "get" function indirectly.
double Matrix::operator() (int i, int j)
{
return data[i*N + j];
}

double Matrix::sum()
{
double total = 0.0;
for (int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
{
    total = total + data[ii];
}


return total;
}

void Matrix::out()
{
for (int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
{
    if (data[ii] == 255)
        cout << "1 ";
    else
        cout << data[ii] << " ";
}
}

// Read .txt file with image of size RxC, and convert to an array of doubles
double* readTXT(char *fileName, int sizeR, int sizeC)
{
double* data = new double[sizeR*sizeC];
int i = 0;
ifstream myfile(fileName);
if (myfile.is_open())
{

    while (myfile.good())
    {
        if (i>sizeR*sizeC - 1) break;
        myfile >> *(data + i);
        // cout << *(data+i) << ' '; // This line display the converted data     on the screen, you may comment it out. 
        i++;
    }
    myfile.close();
}

else cout << "Unable to open file";
//cout << i;

return data;
}

// convert data from double to .pgm stored in filename
void WritePGM(char *filename, double *data, int sizeR, int sizeC, int Q)
{

int i, j;
unsigned char *image;
ofstream myfile;

image = (unsigned char *) new unsigned char[sizeR*sizeC];

// convert the integer values to unsigned char

for (i = 0; i<sizeR*sizeC; i++)
    image[i] = (unsigned char) data[i];

myfile.open(filename, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);

if (!myfile) {
    cout << "Can't open file: " << filename << endl;
    exit(1);
}

myfile << "P5" << endl;
myfile << sizeC << " " << sizeR << endl;
myfile << Q << endl;

myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(image), (sizeR*sizeC)*sizeof(unsigned char));

if (myfile.fail()) {
    cout << "Can't write image " << filename << endl;
    exit(0);
}

myfile.close();

delete[] image;

}
```

The Matrix class header file is as follows:

```
#pragma
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

class Matrix
{
protected:
int M;
int N;
double* data;

public:

Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double* input_data); //Constructor
Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC);
~Matrix(); //Destructor
Matrix(const Matrix& existingMatrix); //Copy Constructor
double get(int i, int j)  const; //Returns value at specified location
const void set(int i, int j, double& val);//Changes value at specified location
int getM() const; //Return value of M
int getN() const; //Return value of N
Matrix getBlock(int startRow, int endRow, int startColumn, int endColumn);//Return section of Matrix
Matrix operator + (const Matrix& B); // addition
Matrix operator = (const Matrix& B); // equals
Matrix operator - (const Matrix& B); // subtraction
Matrix operator * (const Matrix& B); // multiplication
Matrix operator / (const Matrix& B); // division
Matrix operator ++ (); // increment by 1
double operator () (int i, int j);
void out();
double sum();
};

class BinaryImage
:public Matrix
{

public:
BinaryImage(int sizeR, int sizeC, double* input_data, double thresh);
~BinaryImage();
BinaryImage(const Matrix& rhs, double thresh);
BinaryImage(const BinaryImage& existingBinIm);
const void set(int i, int j, double& val);
};

#endif
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, look at this in your getBlock method:

```
return t;
delete[] block;
```

The delete after the return means heap-memory is leaked since block never gets deleted.

Now why you have heap corruption:

You are always going to allocate a block that is 32*32 (see how you are calculating end - start? its always going to be 32)

```
// This is how you call, x = startRow, x+32 is endRow.
Matrix block = ShuffledCode.getBlock(x, (x + 32), y, (y + 32));

// This is inside your method: (endRow is startRow + 32) = 32 always
int Row = endRow - startRow;
```

But inside that method, you are accessing way beyond 32 using the input params. So when the loop gets to i = 1, startRow is 32 and end row is 64. But your matrix only goes to 32!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Think i have massively misunderstood what .getBlock is meant to be doing, i thought it was retrieving datamemberrs in rows and columns 0-32 then creating a smaller matrix containing those values but if the start row/columns and end row/columns variables only dictate the size of the block how is it possible to change the values they contain? For instance if i wanted to put the values held in locations 32,64,32,64 from the ShuffledCode matrix into a block?

Comment: Did you write the impl for that method?

Comment: Get block returns a 32x32 matrix with values from the larger matrix. Anyways, you are close to a solution. The key you are missing is in how you increment inside the getBlock double loop. The value you get from computing k is going to be much larger than the size of the smaller matrix. Convince yourself of this and why that is happening. Then, fix how you are computing k (it is just a matter of scaling it back into the 32x32 range)